# How to get each item's value in React.js

Tags: reactjs

```
const [state, setState] = useState("");
<input onChange={e=>setState(e.target.value)}
```

I know that I can use onChange={} to get each value but I want to get the
(shirts x pants x shoes) when a button onClick={} event happens

```
function Somethingie() {
   return (
      <div>
         Shirts: <input className="one" type="number"></input>
         Pants: <input className="two" type="number"></input>
         Shoes: <input className="three" type="number"></input>
         <br /> <br />
         <button
            onClick={() => {
               console.log(
                  document.querySelector(".one").value *
                     document.querySelector(".two").value *
                     document.querySelector(".three").value
               );
            }}
         >
            Calculate!
         </button>
         <br /> <br />
         Amount of Possible Outfits: <h1 className="result"></h1>
      </div>
   );
}
ReactDOM.render(
   <Somethingie />, 
   document.getElementById("root")
);
```

or do I create an async function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    function Somethingie() {
        return (
               <div>
              Shirts: <input className="one" type="number"></input>
              Pants: <input className="two" type="number"></input>
              Shoes: <input className="three" type="number"></input>
              <br /> <br />
              <button
                 onClick={() => {
                      let x = document.getElementsByClassName('result');
                      x[0].innerHTML =
                      document.querySelector('.one').value *
                      document.querySelector('.two').value *
                      document.querySelector('.three').value;
                         }}
            >
                 Calculate!
            </button>
            <br /> <br />
           Amount of Possible Outfits: <h1 className="result"></h1>
           </div>
         );}

   ReactDOM.render(
   <Somethingie />, 
   document.getElementById("root")
   );
```

You can directly place calculated value as shown in above code snippet.

Comment: why the x[0]? x is not an array, right? other than that all-clear.

Comment: x[0] because in above snippet, x is the array of elements who has the class "result", we have used result class only once in our case that's why x[0].(Output for x is HTMLCollection(2) [h1.result]
0: h1.result
length: 1 )
If we have multiple elements who are using class "result" then we need to specify their indexes.

Answer (score 1):

I would create a state for each input, set the value of the respective input to this state, set the state for each input onChange, and finally, in the onClick of the button just combine the three states.

Example input:

```
const [state1, setState1] = useState("")
...
const change1 = (e) => {
   setState1(e.target.value);
}
...
<input className="one" type="number" value={state1} onChange={change1}/>
```

onClick of the button

```
const handleClick = () => {
   result = state1 * state2 * state3;
}
```

Comment: do I need to know about promises or async function for this?

Comment: No, you don't. Just plain react JavaScript

Comment: how do I get each states values for my onClick function onClick{(var0, var1, var2)=>result}}

Comment: The states are available just like that as variables. You won't need to list them as parameters. See my latest edit

Answer (score 0):

You need to keep each of the data in its own useState like this:

```
import { useState } from "react";

const Combinations = () => {
  const [shirts, setShirts] = useState(0);
  const [pants, setPants] = useState(0);
  const [shoes, setShoes] = useState(0);
  const [total, setTotal] = useState(0);

  const onChange = (e) => {
    console.log(e);
    console.log(typeof e.target.value);
    console.log(Number(e.target.value));

    if (e.target.name === "shirts") setShirts(Number(e.target.value));
    if (e.target.name === "pants") setPants(Number(e.target.value));
    if (e.target.name === "shoes") setShoes(Number(e.target.value));
  };

  const calculate = () => {
    let all = null;

    if (shirts !== 0) {
      if (all === null) {
        all = shirts;
      } else {
        all *= shirts;
      }
    }
    if (pants !== 0) {
      if (all === null) {
        all = pants;
      } else {
        all *= pants;
      }
    }
    if (shoes !== 0) {
      if (all === null) {
        all = shoes;
      } else {
        all *= shoes;
      }
    }

    setTotal(all);
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <label htmlFor="shirts">Shirts: </label>
      <input
        type="number"
        id="shirts"
        name="shirts"
        value={shirts}
        onChange={onChange}
      />
      <br />
      <label htmlFor="pants">Pants: </label>
      <input
        type="number"
        id="pants"
        name="pants"
        value={pants}
        onChange={onChange}
      />
      <br />
      <label htmlFor="shoes">Shoes: </label>
      <input
        type="number"
        id="shoes"
        name="shoes"
        value={shoes}
        onChange={onChange}
      />
      <br />
      <button onClick={calculate}>Calculate!</button>
      <br />
      <p>Amount of Possible Outfits: {total}</p>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: is onChange(e ) listening for any event in that component?

Comment: It's the event listener function we gave react, to be called when the user changes the values of the input.

Comment: I missed the <input onChange={onChange}> all good